# Gunicorn Backlog size monitoring

Tags: gunicorn

I hope you're doing well.

In my application, I have noticed that gunicorn is experiencing lots of backlog connections.

Consequently, this is causing delays in processing client requests as they have to wait for the backlog queue before actual processing begins. As a result, the overall client response time is adversely affected, which is concerning.

To tackle this issue and gain better control over client response time, I am interested in exploring the following approaches:

1. Monitoring the size of the gunicorn backlog: By keeping a close eye on the backlog size, we can identify periods of high demand and potentially adjust the server configuration accordingly to handle increased traffic more efficiently.
2. Monitoring the backlog request waiting time: Understanding the backlog request waiting time will help us pinpoint how long clients are waiting before their requests are taken up for processing. This information can be crucial in identifying potential bottlenecks and optimizing the application's performance.

Is one of these approachs possible?
Is there another approach to solve this issue?

Thank you for your assistance.

Best regards,